# "Hats" link in contents promotion site pointing to 2017 Winter Bash blog announcement

Tags: feature-request, blog, winter-bash

In the [contents promotion site](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/), under the community promotion section the following content is displayed:

> **Community Promotions**
>
> From time to time, communities team up with Stack Exchange, Inc. to celebrate major milestones. When you participate in these promotions, you'll have a chance to win prizes, unlock achievements, and earn our beloved Stack Exchange [hats](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/).

Here the link of "hats" pointing to the [2017 Winter Bash blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/) announcement.
Can be the link pointed to [2018 Winter Bash blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/12/winter-bash-2018-2/) announcement?

Comment: I'm guessing this is [tag:status-bydesign]. It makes sense that it should go to the blog post (to me, at least).